# What is the better way for the function parameter to check data from a certain month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there better way (from the input that I insert to the function parameters) to show data from a certain month ?

This is the code that I used :

```
CREATE FUNCTION fcBestFoodMonth(@date DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT TOP 10 m.Menu_Id, m.Menu_Name, COUNT(*) AS amount
        FROM MENU_ORDER o
        INNER JOIN MENU m
        ON o.Menu_Id_Menu = m.Id_Menu
        AND YEAR(p.Order_Date) = YEAR(@date)
        AND MONTH(p.Order_Date) = MONTH(@date)
        GROUP BY m.Menu_Id, m.Menu_Name
        ORDER BY amount DESC)

-- Then I Call the function like this
SELECT * FROM dbo.fcBestFoodMonth(CAST('2016-11-01' AS datetime2))
```

So, there is two thing I hate about this:

1. I have to input a date ('2016-11-01')
   I was hoping I could just input 2 strings or numeric type which is a month and a year

   Something like ('2016', '11') or (2016, 11)
2. I have to CAST the date parameter.
   While I want to call function as simple like this :

   ```
   SELECT * FROM dbo.fcBestFoodMonth(param1, param2)
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you code something like this:

```
AND YEAR(p.Order_Date) = YEAR(@date)
AND MONTH(p.Order_Date) = MONTH(@date)
```

SQL Server will not be able to use index for Order_Date, because you're using functions. You should be using something like this instead:

```
AND p.Order_Date >= @date
AND p.Order_Date < dateadd(month, 1, @date)
```

This assumes your `@date` variable always contains the first day of the month.

You can of course construct your date from month and year too, if you want that, for example with:

```
set @date = convert(date, convert(varchar(4), @year) + '.' + 
            convert(varchar(2), @month) + '.01', 102)
```

Comment: Can you tell me where should I put the syntax => `set @date = convert(....` ? I dont know where should I declare the `@date` variable If I'm using `@year` and `@month` as the parameters.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could show me the code too.

Comment: That was an example as a variable, but you can of course use that in the place where the variable would be, since inline functions can only have one statement.

Comment: I didnt create date variable, I just put the value of date you wrote on the query and it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to select based on month and year frequently, it could be helpful to add these two columns as **computed columns** to your table definition, and make them **persisted** so you can index over them.

To add the computed columns, use this T-SQL code:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Menu_Order
ADD OrderMonth AS MONTH(Order_Date) PERSISTED;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Menu_Order
ADD OrderYear AS YEAR(Order_Date) PERSISTED;
```

Now your select could use these two extra columns in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    m.Menu_Id, m.Menu_Name, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM 
    MENU_ORDER o
INNER JOIN 
    MENU m ON o.Menu_Id_Menu = m.Id_Menu
           AND o.OrderYear = YEAR(@date)
           AND o.OrderMonth = MONTH(@date)
GROUP BY 
    m.Menu_Id, m.Menu_Name
ORDER BY 
    count DESC
```

And as these columns are persisted (actually, physically stored on disk), you could even add them into an index, if that would speed your query up.

Since you're using the `Id_Menu` along with month and year as the joining clause between the two tables, I would probably try this index first:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Id_Month_Year
   ON dbo.Menu_Order(Id_Menu, OrderMonth, OrderYear);
```

and see if that helps anything with this query.

The signature of your function could now also be changed to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fcBestFoodMonth(@OrderMonth INT, @OrderYear INT)
```

and then you can use these two `int` values in the `WHERE` clause to further simplify your query.